# Excel-VBA-How to add new row to end of table and unlock new row?

Tags: excel, vba, row

The following works to add a new row to the end of the table and unlock that row.  However, I keep getting "Run-Time Error 424: Object Required" despite completing the action.

Don't know why this is happening.

```
Sub AddRowToTable()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim tbl As ListObject
Dim lastRow As ListRow

Set ws = ActiveSheet

Set tbl = ws.ListObjects("Table1")
tbl.ListRows.Add 

Set lastRow = tbl.Range.Rows(tbl.Range.Rows.Count).Row
lastRow.Locked = False


End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `tbl.ListRows(tbl.ListRows.Count)` instead of `tbl.Range.Rows(tbl.Range.Rows.Count).Row`

```
Sub AddRowToTable()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim tbl As ListObject
    Dim lastRow As ListRow
    
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    
    Set tbl = ws.ListObjects("Table1")
    tbl.ListRows.Add
    
    Set lastRow = tbl.ListRows(tbl.ListRows.Count)
    lastRow.Range.Locked = False
End Sub
```

Comment: It works!  But for some reason, when I ran it the first time, it didn't work and there was no error.  But from the 2nd click on it starts working unless I manually reset and delete all the new rows I just added and lock those rows.  Is that a glitch or something?

Comment: @MohamadBachrouche Everything works the first time. It's just that in an empty table, the first row is not a row, but a place to insert the first row, but they look the same. Therefore, at the first click, the place for inserting the first line is replaced with the first line.

Answer (score -1):

I am using this script can add new row at last table, do you have recorded script for locking table? maybe this can be used to unlocked it

```
Sub AddRowToTable2()

Dim ws As Worksheet

Dim tbl As ListObject
Set ws = ActiveSheet

Dim lr As Long

Set tbl = ws.ListObjects("Table1")
tbl.ListRows.Add

End Sub
```

[run 2x script adding 2 new rows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0nciW.png)

Comment: This does not work